# paypal create recurring profile showing the next payment date same as profile start date

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

The created profile of recurring paypal is showing the next Payment date same as profile start date i think it should show the next payment date to next month, following is the array format that i am sending to create profile.

```
 Array
 (
[0] => 
[1] => AMT=9.99
[2] => CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa
[3] => ACCT=4662886735437488
[4] => EXPDATE=092017
[5] => CVV2=121
[6] => FIRSTNAME=Naeem+Bhatti
[7] => LASTNAME=
[8] => STREET=my+address+1
[9] => CITY=westchester
[10] => STATE=Alabama
[11] => ZIP=eq2
[12] => COUNTRYCODE=US
[13] => CURRENCYCODE=USD
[14] => PROFILESTARTDATE=2012-10-01T0%3A0%3A0
[15] => BILLINGPERIOD=Month
[16] => BILLINGFREQUENCY=1
[17] => DESC=Zimmapp Payment
[18] => EMAIL=naeembhatti@gmail.com
[19] => PAYMENTACTION=Sale
[20] => AUTOBILLAMT=AddToNextBilling
[21] => BILLINGTYPE=RecurringPayments
[22] => TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=0
 )
```

and this is how the profile creates.

```
 Profile ID I-74V7UV5N4SBT
 Product/service    Zimmapp Payment
 Start date Oct 1, 2012
 End date   Indefinite - continue until canceled
 Next payment date  Oct 1, 2012

 Payment type   Regular Recurring Payment
 Payment cycle  Monthly
 Total cycles   Indefinite
 Cycles remaining   Indefinite
 Amount due per cycle   $9.99 USD Details
 Amount received    $0.00 USD
```

what i want is monthly charges of 9.99 to user, but next payment date is same? please suggest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i have found out the solution, Paypal change the next payment date after a day pass on sandbox account, when i came back next day all next payment dates are corrected.

Comment: +1 for coming back to offer the solution you've found.

Comment: Do they send a fresh IPN when they correct the dates?