# Setting up a recurring payment with PayPal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I set up a **recurring payment system** for my subscribers within my web application.

Each subscription is characterized by a 3**0-days test period** followed by a **regular period**.

Following the creation of a subscription at **01/20/2016**, the value of "**Next payment due**" is the same as the value of "**Profile start date**."

So What's the problem please ? is there a bug ?

[image]

Comment: I just checked my website's paypal subscriptions, I can see that next payment due has a correct date. I suspect that in your case since you're using sandbox that might be the issue for what you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, currently i'm using sandbox but the value of the "Next payment due" Sometimes is correcte and sometimes is  not correcte

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667811/paypal-create-recurring-profile-showing-the-next-payment-date-same-as-profile-st

Comment: thank you my buddy, So when i use sandbox "Next payment due" is not immediately updated.